Chrome web app notification bubbles on the dock
I've noticed that Chrome Web App notifications don´t work very well within the Ubuntu Dock. I believe that is because Gnome sees all those "Chrome" as the same instances instead of different ones.
This isn´t a big issue, but I noticed that when you have multiple web apps (MS Teams and WhatsApp, for example), the Gnome Notification will show as a notification from the last web app that was opened.
This also affects the Ubuntu badge counter because it treats every Chrome/Web app notification as just one app. So if I have Microsoft Teams, WhatsApp, and Todoist open on the dock (all as Chrome web apps), the bubble shows a notification for only one.
Has anyone noticed a similar issue, and is there any workaround?
Edit: Ubuntu 24.04, but I saw on 23.10 previously too.

Sounds like an issue Chrome folks need to deal with. Would also be helpful if the question had the Ubuntu version info in it.

Unfortunately, I think so. I've added the Ubuntu version to the description
